# Can't locate unicore/Canonical.pl in @INC

Tags: perl, upgrade

I tried to upgrade my custom perl version from 5.10.1 to 5.16.3, and now I am getting following errors in my logs:

> [Wed May 21 00:05:32 2014] [error] Can't locate unicore/Canonical.pl
>   in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/test/perl/lib/5.10.1/i686-linux
>   /opt/test/perl/lib/5.10.1
>   /opt/test/perl/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/i686-linux
>   /opt/test/perl/lib/site_perl/5.10.1 . /opt/test/httpd) at
>   /opt/test/perl/lib/5.10.1/utf8_heavy.pl line 139.\n

Can anyone please help me to sort it out?

Comment: Did you use perlbrew to install it? How did you go about doing the upgrade? Personally, I just use perlbrew to compile and install the new version separately, then do use http://perlbrew.pl/Reinstall-All-Modules-On-New-Perl.html to install the modules I had before (where possible).

Comment: Please give some information about how you where "upgrading" (looks like a parallel install to me, afaik /opt is not a standard per path) and when the error appears. Do you have a script/source for us or is this error coming "out of nowhere"? ...

Answer (score 0):

try re-installing the missing modules using cpan.

the "upgrade" probably created a second, parallel Perl installation on your system...

did you then remove the 'old' version?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below commands:

1/ Install cpan with `yum install cpan` or `apt-get install cpan`

2/ On the command prompt enter: `cpan install unicore:Canonical`

Comment: `unicore:Canonical` is not the correct name for the package. What in the OP leads you to believe this is a `yum`-based system? (genuinely curious)